# Check uniform equicontinuity of a function family

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am struggling to prove or disprove that the following function family is uniformly equicontinuous.
$$F = \{f \in C^1[0,1]:  \forall x \text{ } |f(x)| + \sqrt x |f'(x)| \leq 1 \}$$

First I tried to disprove the statement with functions like $f_n(x) = C\sqrt{x + \frac{1}{n}}$ (which are in $F$ for some real valued constant $C$) but I completely forgot that $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous so my counterexample failed.

Now I am beginning to think that this family is uniformly equicontinuous, but I can't prove it.

Well for $x, y$ such that $x < y$ and $|x - y| < \delta$ by mean value theorem I get 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(c)|(y - x) \leq \frac{y - x}{\sqrt{c}} \leq \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{c}} \leq \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x}}$$ for some $c \in [x, y]$. After that I am just out of ideas what to do next.

P.S. I want to use Arzelà–Ascoli theorem afterwards.

Comment: Forget about the mean value theorem. You have a uniform majorisation of $\lvert f'(x)\rvert$ by an integrable function.

Comment: @DanielFischer How can this help me, can you please explain? Well I understand that for each $f \in F$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $|f(x)| \leq 2 \sqrt{x}$ as far as $x \in [0, \delta]$. But don't I need unique choice on  $\delta$ for all $f$ to prove uniform equicontinuity?

Comment: Think of the fundamental theorem of calculus. You want a bound on $f(y) - f(x) = \dotsc$.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK, I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer suggested, we can generalize in the following way: if $g\colon (0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is integrable, then the family 
$$
F:=\left\{f\in C^1[0,1]:\forall t\in (0,1], \left\lvert f'(t)\right\rvert\leqslant g(t)\right\},
$$
is equicontinuous. Indeed, let $x,y\in [0,1]$, $x<y$, then 
$$
\left\lvert f(x)-f(y)\right\rvert=\left\lvert \int_x^y f'(t)\mathrm dt\right\rvert
\leqslant \int_x^y \left\lvert f'(t)\mathrm dt\right\rvert\leqslant \int_x^y \left\lvert f'(t)\right\rvert\mathrm dt\leqslant \int_x^y g(t) \mathrm dt.$$
We conclude by using the (uniform) continuity of the map $x\mapsto \int_0^x g(t)\mathrm dt$.

In the situation of the opening post, $g(t)=t^{-1/2}$.